# MySQL Query: Get 3 results where id equals this, then another 3 where id equals that

Tags: mysql

I have the following:

TABLE: topics
COLS: topicId, categoryId (linking to the categoryId in categories)

TABLE: categories
COLS: categoryId

For the sake of this discussion, lets pretend the topic table has 100 rows with topicIds 100 through 200, and each row is associated with varying categoryIds 1 - 10.  Assume each categoryId is in there 10 times randomly through; not in order.
Categories then has 10 rows with categoryIds:  1 through 10

I want to write a query that reads like (I know this isn't right):

```
SELECT topicId FROM topics WHERE categoryId = 1 OR categoryId = 2 OR categoryID = 3 LIMIT 3 topicIds per categoryId
```

The result should be that I pull 9 rows from the database.  3 of the rows are associated with categoryId 1, 3 with catId 2, 3 with catId 4.

How can I do this?  I'm stumped.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
(SELECT topicId
    FROM topics
    WHERE categoryId = 1
    LIMIT 3)
UNION ALL
(SELECT topicId
    FROM topics
    WHERE categoryId = 2
    LIMIT 3)
UNION ALL
(SELECT topicId
    FROM topics
    WHERE categoryId = 3
    LIMIT 3)
```